# I lost my Pegassi Oppressor Mk II after replacing it, how do I get it back?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I had a garage which was full and I had two other garages from other properties so I bought a car and tried to make it deliver to the one that's full as it's my main garage.

When I tried, it said that it's full and I'll have to replace a vehicle in order to get it delivered there. I thought that the vehicle I will choose to replace would just go to my other garage, so I chose Mk II and after it was replaced I can't find it anywhere now. I tried looking at all my garages but nothing. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can get it back.  You will have to buy that vehicle again!

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to return it. When purchasing the car you clicked on "Replace".

Even if you contacted R* support they'll more than likely ignore your request, due to the fact you did that yourself.

Kinda rough that you just lost a like 3 mil investment, but there's nothing you can do, sorry.